# Python "if string" expression in Java

Tags: java, python, if-statement, boolean-expression

In Python one can write `if "string"` to test if a string is blank <strike>or contains all white-space characters.</strike>

```
if "somestring":
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)

Output: True

if "":
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)

Output: False
```

How could this easily be done in Java?

One could do the following, but the statement would evaluate to false if `someString` contained any white-space characters:

```
if( someString.equals("") {
    System.out.println(true);
} else {
    System.out.println(false);
}
```

Comment: "to test if a string is blank or contains all white-space characters." ...Actually, no. Only strings that are actually empty are considered falsey.

Answer (score 3):

I think the closest to your answer is: `someString.trim().isEmpty()`

---

Edit: Thank to [@user1886323](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1886323/user1886323), you should also check for `null`. Actually, it is not a good idea (like myself) to reinvent the wheel.

If you need to know exactly what did they do in the Apache Commons StringUtils, you can check here [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) (from line 296).

Comment: One reason to avoid re-inventing the wheel is that your code is vulnerable to NPEs, whereas StringUtils.isBlank() is not.

Comment: @user1886323: +1 for null case.

Answer (score 3):

The Apache Commons [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) class contains helper methods for this, such as isEmpty(), isBlank(), isNotEmpty() and isNotBlank(). [For example:](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.java)

```
StringUtils.isBlank(null)      = true
StringUtils.isBlank("")        = true
StringUtils.isBlank(" ")       = true
StringUtils.isBlank("bob")     = false
StringUtils.isBlank("  bob  ") = false
```

If you are unwilling/unable to add a dependency on this library then you can copy the source into your own project as it is open source.

Comment: If he only needs isEmpty() he probably doesn't need the dependency since it looks like String class has had an isEmpty() implementation since 1.6: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()

Comment: isEmpty() will return false for " ". The author has indicated that they are interested in Strings that have whitespace, hence both answers posted so far to cater for this require more than just isEmpty().

Comment: Right, I meant to imply that he would need some form of trim() as well. Just noting that you don't need StringUtils anymore to check if a string is empty.

Comment: The two are semantically different - one handles nulls, the other blows up. Depending on the situation both approaches have value.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's true. My mistake!

Comment: No worries, it's not a mistake. Both have their merits!